# finding the index/position of a character in the URL format

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, nsregularexpression

I have the following url:

```
http://test.me/s/hq6aN
```

I basically wanted to replace that s with an d, what is the best way to do this using NSRegularExpression easily? Essentially what I want is to figure out the index of the /s/ in a string any idea how?

Here's what I have so far:

```
NSString *regexStr = @"/s/";
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexStr options:0 error:&error];
    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:shortLink options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [shortLink length])];
    if ([matches count] > 0){
         NSTextCheckingResult *matchesIndex = [matches objectAtIndex:0];
         NSRange range = matchesIndex.range;
    }
```

I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong with the regexStr

Comment: How about just `[url 
        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/s/" withString:@"/d/"];`? Is there any other reason for using regex here?

Comment: Ha, now that you mention that, my answer **does** seem like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern looks fine, but there's a convenience method for doing search-and-replace that allows you to write this much more succinctly:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"/s/" options:0 error:&error];
NSMutableString *haystack = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"http://test.me/s/hq6aN"];
[regex replaceMatchesInString:haystack options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [haystack length]) withTemplate:@"/d/"];
```

There is an equivalent `-stringByReplacingMatchesInString:options:range:withTemplate:` for `NSStrings` if you'd prefer to keep the string containing the original URL immutable.